# Pine script table working for some symbols but not working for other symbols

Tags: pine-script

I have a working script that display tables correctly. However when i chose another symbol or stock the table do not show any calculations and return NaN

So this works fine on "Nifty" but doesnt work if I choose "NIFTY1!" symbol for example, only shows NaN in the results. Any directions around this will be greatly appreciable

=============================================

Below is the reproducible script

```
    //@version=4
study(title="test", shorttitle="test",overlay=true,format=format.price)

i_startTime = input(defval = timestamp("01 Jan 2021 09:00 +0530"), title = "Start Time", type = input.time)
i_endTime = input(defval = timestamp("31 Mar 2022 15:30 +0530"), title = "End Time", type = input.time)
inDateRange = time >= i_startTime and time <= i_endTime

StrategyLongCond = crossover(ema(close, 8), ema(open, 9) ) 
StrategyShortCond = crossunder(ema(close, 8), ema(open, 9)) 

plotshape(StrategyLongCond ,title="Buy Signal", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar,color=color.blue, display=display.all)
plotshape(StrategyShortCond,title="Sell Signal", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar,color=color.red, display=display.all)
    
StrategyLongCondCount= sum((StrategyLongCond and inDateRange? 1 : 0), 4999)
StrategyShortCondCount= sum((StrategyShortCond and inDateRange? 1 : 0), 4999)
TradeSignalCount = StrategyLongCondCount + StrategyShortCondCount 


var table Display = table.new(position.bottom_right, 5, 50)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(Display, 1, 4, "Sgnl", bgcolor = color.new(color.blue, 90), text_size=size.small)
    table.cell(Display, 1, 5, tostring(TradeSignalCount), bgcolor = color.new(color.gray,90), text_size=size.small)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: As a guess, you're using strategy script. `barstate.islast` will be `true` afrer the last charts bar will be closed. Try other barstates, like `barstate.islastconfirmedhistory or barstate.isrealtime`

Comment: @StarrLucky Yes i tried that to no avail

Comment: @vitruvius I have added the reproducible code. So when i run this as is on "Nifty" symbol it gives me 106 signals, but when I change the symbol to Nifty1! it gives me "NAN"

Comment: @vitruvius updated the reproducible script on my question..

Comment: @StarrLucky No it's a study script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is because you are using `4999` in your `sum()` function. That means you want to check 4999 bars for your calculation.

However, if there are less than 4999 bars on your chart, you will have the issue you described. It is not chart specific. You will have the same issue if you go to Nifty with a timeframe 1 week or higher.

You can actually use a simple counter for what you want to do.

```
var buy_cnt = 0
var sell_cnt = 0

buy_cnt := (StrategyLongCond and inDateRange) ? buy_cnt + 1 : buy_cnt
sell_cnt := (StrategyShortCond and inDateRange) ? sell_cnt + 1 : sell_cnt
total_cnt = buy_cnt + sell_cnt

var table Display = table.new(position.bottom_right, 5, 50)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(Display, 1, 1, "Sgnl", bgcolor = color.new(color.blue, 20), text_size=size.normal)
    table.cell(Display, 1, 2, tostring(TradeSignalCount), bgcolor = color.new(color.gray,20), text_size=size.normal)
    table.cell(Display, 1, 3, tostring(total_cnt), bgcolor = color.new(color.gray,20), text_size=size.normal)
```

Comment: fabulous that's what the problem is and so dumb of me to not check that on other time frames. Thank you so much for the direction. I will try the solution you mentioned thanks again both for your responses